# login failed error At restore database sql in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am trying to restore database with this code :

```
OpenFileDialog open1 = new OpenFileDialog();
open1.FilterIndex = 1;
open1.Title = "restory backup databse";
open1.Filter = "Backup File (*.Bak)|*.Bak";

if (open1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (back_restore(@"Alter DataBase [Attendance_DB] set single_User with Rollback Immediate use master Restore Database [Attendance_DB] From Disk  ='" + open1.FileName + "' with Replace "))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("successfully restored");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

and

```
public static bool back_restore (string Query)
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection();
    Con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Attendance_DB;Integrated Security=True";
    Con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

    Con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con);

    Con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = false;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Con.Close();
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot open database "Attendance_DB" requested by the login. The login failed.

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: User ID=UserName;Password=Password" is required

Comment: Did you try to login using your SQL Server itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is some information missing to answer this question precisely,
First of all make sure that 
1- The `"Attendance_DB"` actually exists.
2- If it does exist and you cannot run the commands, run your utility as admin. Or if you are running the code in some IDE, run the IDE as administrator.
3- Make sure the DB Server accepts the `Windows Authentication` since you are using `Integrated Security=True"` in your connection string.
HTH